# alignment issue of div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a web page where on click of a button I can add `div` tags. What I thought to do was that I'll create two `div` tags within a single `div` so that over all presentation will be uniform and similar to a table having two columns and multiple rows and the first column contains only label's and second column will contain `textbox`.

Here is the JS file:

```
        var counter = 0;

function create_div(type){
        var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");

             dynDiv.id = "divid_"+counter;
             dynDiv.class="main";
             document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
             question();
             if(type == 'ADDTEXTBOX'){
                ADDTEXTBOX();
             }

             counter=counter+1;
        }

    function question(){
        var question_div = document.createElement("div");
            question_div.class="question";
            question_div.id = "question_div_"+counter;
            var Question = prompt("Enter The Question here:", "");

            var node=document.createTextNode(Question);
            question_div.appendChild(node);
            var element=document.getElementById("divid_"+counter);   
            element.appendChild(question_div);
        }

    function ADDTEXTBOX(){
            var answer_div = document.createElement("div");
            answer_div.class="answer";
            answer_div.id = "answer_div_"+counter;
            var answer_tag = document.createElement("input");
                    answer_tag.id = "answer_tag_"+counter;
                    answer_tag.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    answer_tag.setAttribute("name", "textbox");
                        answer_div.appendChild(answer_tag);

            var element=document.getElementById("divid_"+counter);
            element.appendChild(answer_div);
        }
```

Here is the css file:

```
.question
{
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.answer
{
    padding-left:10%;
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.main
{   
    width: auto;
    background-color:gray;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

My problem is that the code is working properly but both the divisions are not coming in a straight line. after the first div prints on the screen the second divisions comes in another line. How can I make both the `div's` come in the same line?

PS: should I stick with the current idea of using div or should I try some other approach? like tables?

Comment: I think the Problem lies in the code with  `question_div.class="question";` line because as I tried to debug my code I didn't found any style definition of div tags.
can anyone please tell me the correct syntax ?

Comment: And what HTML are you starting with?

Comment: Thats no biggie just calling the `create_div(type)` on click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its in diffrent lines lies in your JS code, try setting your class like following:

```
           //question_div.class="question";
        question_div.setAttribute("class", "question") ;
```

and

```
            //answer_div.class="answer";
        answer_div.setAttribute("class", "answer");
```

**and also this:**

```
//dynDiv.class="main";
dynDiv.setAttribute("class", "main");
```

Your divs have not class attribute set properly. I recommend chrome in-built tools for developers or FireBug add-on if you use Firefox to check whether elements you built are like you design them to be. 
You may check code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nnwbs/2/

```
      var counter = 0;

function create_div(type){
    var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");

         dynDiv.id = "divid_"+counter;
         //dynDiv.class="main";
         dynDiv.setAttribute("class", "main"); 
         document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
         question();
         if(type == 'ADDTEXTBOX'){
            ADDTEXTBOX();
         }

         counter=counter+1;
    }

function question(){
    var question_div = document.createElement("div");
       //question_div.class="question";
        question_div.setAttribute("class", "question") ;  
        question_div.id = "question_div_"+counter;
        var Question = prompt("Enter The Question here:", "");

        var node=document.createTextNode(Question);
        question_div.appendChild(node);
        var element=document.getElementById("divid_"+counter);   
        element.appendChild(question_div);

    }

function ADDTEXTBOX(){
        var answer_div = document.createElement("div");
        //answer_div.class="answer";
        answer_div.setAttribute("class", "answer");            
        answer_div.id = "answer_div_"+counter;
        var answer_tag = document.createElement("input");
                answer_tag.id = "answer_tag_"+counter;
                answer_tag.setAttribute("type", "text");
                answer_tag.setAttribute("name", "textbox");
                    answer_div.appendChild(answer_tag);

        var element=document.getElementById("divid_"+counter);
        element.appendChild(answer_div);

}
create_div("ADDTEXTBOX");
```

​And about that aproach I mean div or tables, you are correct to use div, its generaly recommended to do so.

Also after you correct your JS code fix also a bit your css styles as you like.

Comment: Also remember to change how you add your main class  //dynDiv.class="main"; dynDiv.setAttribute("class", "main") ;

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome using inspect element and find the corresponding 'div' tag and try to adjust the style(position)

Comment: as you can see I have already defined width to be 40% in both the divs. so it should come in a single line by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to position both Divs with absolute inside a main div that could be relative. something like

```
#mainDiv {
    position:absolute; /* or relative depends how you have it*/
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    left:10%;
}
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height:100%;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. To line up both div's, give the position of of the two div's as display:inline-block;

```
display:inline-block;
```

Note: BOTH div's have to have this property for them to appear in a line.